Нужна запятая в этом предложении?
Возник спор о запятой после слова "Африки". Нужно ли ее ставить?
Если нужно, обоснуйте, пожалуйста, правилом.
Цитата из Википедии:
"В странах Аравийского полуострова и перечисленных выше странах Восточной Африки(,) Кат является неотъемлемой частью жизни общества..."

Правильно:
В странах Аравийского полуострова и перечисленных выше странах Восточной Африки / Кат является неотъемлемой частью жизни общества...
По правилам Розенталя нет причин для актуализации (смыслового выделения) обстоятельственного оборота со значением места. При чтении делается произносительная пауза, которая не обозначается запятой.
В то же время распространенность оборота может затруднять понимание предложения. В таких случаях возможен присоединительный оборот с союзом А ТАКЖЕ:
В странах Аравийского полуострова, а также в перечисленных выше странах Восточной Африки, Кат является неотъемлемой частью жизни общества...
Примечание: кат — нарицательное существительное, пишется со строчной буквы. Требуется уточнение правомерности прописной буквы.

То есть, не нужна запятая?

Нет, не нужна. Ее сложно обосновать. Такой оборот в начале предложения обычно выделяется с причинным значением, одной распространенности недостаточно для постановки запятой. А здесь нет дополнительного причинного значения.
